# What happens when the mega corp turns evil?

Tags: dystopia, economy, conspiracy

Famously, Google's founding motto was "Don't be evil."

Imagine, if you will, a corporation called FooTec that, while like Google in interests, capabilities, and assets, has chosen a different path. FooTec, having reached the top of the corporate food chain by grudgingly following the rules (and occasionally breaking them within the accepted bounds of tolerance), has decided to "go evil." Specifically, the board has decided that they want to drop all pretenses of morality, idealism, social responsibility etc... and that they will instead seek to obtain as much wealth and power as they can. I'm not merely talking cut-throat business practices... I'm talking overt insurrection against the ruling government and social order for the purpose of taking over all means of production and authority. They want it all, and they are willing to go "all in," leveraging their accumulated wealth and knowledge to get it.

Assume the time and setting is present day America. What are some likely scenarios for FooTec's coup? Where would they start? Could they win? How could they be stopped?

Comment: Make medecine, and "invent" new diseases to be cured by this medecine

Comment: They would probably start by throwing their wealth behind running for president...then legislate their actions as 'their way or the highway'.

Comment: [Look to history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_United_States_antitrust_law), [recent examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_scandal), and Bond villains.

Comment: I'm sure it'll depend on what FooTec actually did when it was legitimate. Was it a tech company like Google? Or was it a pharmaceutical company? The actual strengths and capabilities of FooTec at the time it goes rogue will define *how* it goes rogue.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand why this question was put on hold for being opinion based... there are several other questions like this with an open yet clearly scoped question. Oh well. Thanks at least to those who did comment. The ways of stack exchange still mystify me I suppose.

Comment: Perhaps this was closed because the megacorp's eyes–and–ears didn't like this question!  In a more serious vein, and with disregard to what some people accept elsewhere here, I have a few ideas you might want to consider if you were interested in editing this question:  Split it in several individual questions — it seems here like you are asking at least five; supply us with a little more backstory and characterization; revise your core question to being more ‘what economic conditions would make such an overt transformation useful or viable?’

Comment: Use lobbyists to buy off all politicians and enough bureaucrats. Once they've done that, they own the government. For further details, look at recent world history, basically any major organization from 3 CE.

Comment: What happened at 3CE?